# Results I proved myself: already proved? Reference?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

In the context of writing my thesis, I think I managed to prove the following results:

[image]

[image]

I was wondering: have these been proved before? Maybe some of these things even have a name? Is there a book or article available online where these (or some of them) are proved?

**EDIT**

**1: context**

One commenter suggested I ask my advisor about this. Now my thesis is about the eigenvalues of Aharonov-Bohm operators, and my advisor works in PDEs, so I wouldn't really expect her to know of a book where such topological results are found. Indeed, she suggested I look for a reference saying these things «seem rather classical» to her.

What are these doing in my thesis? Well, I was trying to prove Lemma 2.3 of [this article](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00959975/document), and in particular the implication that if a potential $A$ on a Lipschitz domain $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ has normalized circulations $\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_\gamma A\cdot dr\in\mathbb Z$ for all closed loops $\gamma$ in $\Omega$, then it is gauge equivalent to zero, i.e. there exists $\psi\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\Omega)$ which is univalued and satisfies $A=-i\frac{\nabla\psi}{\psi}$. This is easy on simply connected domains, so I thought I'd try to split my domain into simply connected pieces that overlapped so that I could define gauge functions on each piece and glue them together. And that is where the theorem came from. When I got to applied it, I realized it was easier to work by induction on the number of holes, hence the corollary.

**2: definitions**

A *Lipscthiz domain of the plane* is an open set $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ such that, for all $x\in\partial\Omega$, there exists $r>0$ such that $B_r\cap\partial\Omega$ is the graph of a Lipschitz function $f_x:I\to\mathbb R$ where $I$ is a suitable interval.

I guess this does classify as "the interior of a compact codimension zero submanifold", as another commenter put it. However, to apply his argument, I would have to see how the theorem then follows from the classification of surfaces, and I still would have to refer to a proof of that result, which, in my experience, is, for me, pretty hard to follow, so I'd be leaving a potential reader with this incredibly powerful cannon which is very hard to prove but then gives the theorem in a second. I personally prefer to have a simpler-to-follow proof like the one I gave (assuming it works), and have it in the thesis, to avoid further references.

A *Jordan curve* is a closed simple curve, that is, a map $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$ that is continuous, is injective on $[0,1)$ and $(0,1]$, and satisfies $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$. By the classification of topological 1-manifolds (and such a curve is certainly a 1-manifold), this equates to having a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ homeomorphic to $S^1$, the unit circle.

An "overlapping partition", as I say in the theorem, is a decomposition into pieces such that no one piece is disjoint from all other pieces.

**Final Note**

The corollary is really a corollary of the proof of the theorem, not so much of the theorem itself.

**Addendum**

I have been asked for a (sketch of a) proof. Now, this question is 2 years 10 months old, and my master's degree (in the thesis for which I had this theorem) dates to March 2018, so I've essentially forgotten everything. Here is Appendix A from my thesis, which contains a proof of like half the theorem.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm too lazy to convert the TeX code to a format that MathJax would render, or add all the shortcut commands this code uses as `\newcommand` at the top of the post. As for the "overlapping partition" part and the corollary, I don't know. They're probably hidden somewhere in the thesis.

EDIT Actually the screenshots at post beginning seem to be from a file called `Tesi_Magi_wrong-result.tex`, an old version of the thesis, probably from the old version of the above Appendix A. So the overlapping partition was apparently scrapped from the result.

Comment: Your advisor is definitely someone to ask about this ...

Comment: @NoahSchweiber She told me to look for a reference. I tried Googling but found nothing. I don't think this is something she would know, since her field is PDE and the thesis indeed is about Aharonov-Bohm operators and their eigenvalues. These are in an appendix because they are used in constructing a gauge function for a potential with circulations all zero on a Lipschitz domain of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: You are missing a fair number of definitions. For instance, what is a Lipschitz domain? If it is the interior of a compact codimension 0 topological submanifold with boundary in $R^2$ then the claims are just a corollary of the classification theorem for surfaces.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I added a few definitions to the question. I also added the reason I'd prefer a direct proof to a reference for that theorem plus explaining why my results follow from it (which doesn't seem exactly trivial to me anyway).

Comment: Dear @MickG, could you provide a (sketch of) proof of your structure theorem?  This seems cool!

Comment: @MocaAoba See addendum.